# In pygame blit of subsurface cause error that the subsurface is locked

Tags: python, pygame

Here is a minimal script to reproduce that

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pygame

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
screen_half = screen.subsurface((0,0, 640/2.0, 480))

print screen.get_locks()
print screen_half.get_locks()
screen_half.blit(screen_half, (0, 0))
```

the output is

```
()
()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./blit_test.py", line 10, in <module>
    screen_half.blit(screen_half, (0, 0))
pygame.error: Surfaces must not be locked during blit
```

As you can see tuples with locks for **screen** and **screen_half** are empty. There is no error if I use **screen** instead of **screen_half**.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem and pmoreli is right. I just copied subsurface creating new surface and than blit it on display:

```
screen_half = screen_half.copy()
screen_half.blit(screen_half, (0, 0))
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. I had a hard tine with this insane Pygame error! I visited a lot of places base on this subject but no handling. So this answer definetely deserves a lot of upvotes (there were only 2 before mine)! Unfortunately, the simplest and best answers are not appreciated ...

Answer (score 1):

Probably the lock occurs during the blit.
You're blitting a surface into itself, that's why you get the error.

If you want to copy half of the screen into the other half, you can ".copy" the subsurface and then blit it.

Comment: But blit works on surface. It doesn't work on subsurfaces. Anyway I found that for my purposes I should use screen_half.scroll()